Компиляция ядра линукса при запуске ОС
помогите разобраться, я не понимаю как именно происходит компиляция ядра линукса при запуске ОС. Я так понимаю, что сначала разработчики дистрибутива скачивают ядро с офф сайта, дорабатывают его и компилируют, потом образно прикручивают GNU или что-то наподобие него и получается полноценная ОС. Но когда я запускаю ОС, она сначала компилируется, определяются аппаратные устройства, выделяется память и тд, я не понимаю на каком уровне происходит компиляция, ведь ОС еще не запущена, чтобы она могла скомпилировать его.

Ничего не компилируется при запуске, запускается заранее скомпилированное

вы путаете компиляцию ядра, загрузку ядра, сборку дистрибутива. По загрузке ядра можно посмотреть информацию в той же википедии Процесс_загрузки_Linux#Фаза_ядра

спасибо, ознакомлюсь.

Компиляция ядра не происходит при запуске ОС. То, что вы видите на экране - это именно процесс запуска ядра. Ядро уже скомпилировано на стороне разработчиков дистрибутива, и распространяется в готовом виде через репозиторий дистрибутива в виде самых обычных пакетов (RPM/DEB, например).
Также ядро можно скомпилировать вручную. Вот гайд (на английском) для Fedora: https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/quick-docs/kernel-build-custom/. Также есть неофициальный гайд для Ubuntu (тоже на английском) - https://davidaugustat.com/linux/how-to-compile-linux-kernel-on-ubuntu.
